# Difference between using relational database and relational database-object

Tags: database, oracle, relational-database, object-oriented-database

What's the diference between using relational database and relational database-object(hybrid).

Im making an application of adverts. Using common relational database, i think I could make  tables of each type of adverts: cars,technology,estates,employment, services, this is the way a I do it.But reading about relational database-object I found that you can create a type field in the database(Oracle) that allows you to encapsulate another fields and methods, so what if I make only a table of adverts, knowing that all adverts have fields in common like title, description,the date it publish, images, but I can add a field that encapsulate another objects that will be cars,technology, employment, and inside of each one encapsulate attributes to them like
 cars(model,brand,price),
 technology(state,price,accesories,dimensions)
 emloyment(job,payment)

Well this is the idea, actually for every advert you can actually enlarged the functionality, making a database for each one.
My question is: what are the potencial problems using relational database-object?
What is the best option?

Answer (score 3):

Most if not all, of the worst database designs of the last ten years have at their root tables built to an object model rather than fitted to a relational model.

OOP is a *programming* thang; its concept of combining behaviour and data together works well when building APIs, etc.  But it sucks when it comes to persistence, leading to horribly large tables, lots of duplicated data and monstrously slow queries.  I'm not saying that's inevitable but it is the way to bet.

So why does Oracle support Types in the database?  Because there are advantages to defining complex data types with behaviour: XMLType is one such, and Oracle Spatial makes extensive use of objects.  But these usages are limited to individual columns of regular relational tables.  The intention is not, and never has been, that we use object tables to store all the data in the database.

By all means use Types in your Pl/SQL programming.  I have done this extensively, and for the right use case they can be extremely effective.  Just don't store your data in them.

Answer (score 0):

The most significant difference is that Oracle's object-relational technology is rarely used.

Very few programmers or DBAs have significant experience with object-relational technology.  Database tools do not support objects well, or at all.  Oracle does not support the technology well - it's buggy and does not get updated frequently.

Of course, just because a feature is rare does not mean you should ignore it.  There are cases where Oracle's object-relational features work very well.  But if you're planing to build a significant part of your database using objects, you need to consider the loss of skills, technology, and support.